# Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am getting error whenever i tried to give the below mappings.

Is there anything you need to do for "copy_to".

```
PUT myindex/mytype/_mapping
{
  "mappings": {
  "properties": {
  "manufacturer": {
    "type": "string",
    "copy_to": "full_make_model_name"
  },
  "name": {
    "type": "string",
    "copy_to": "full_make_model_name"
  },
  "full_make_model_name": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "analyzed"
  }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
PUT myindex/_mapping/mytype
{
  "properties": {
  "manufacturer": {
    "type": "string",
    "copy_to": "full_make_model_name"
  },
  "name": {
    "type": "string",
    "copy_to": "full_make_model_name"
  },
  "full_make_model_name": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "analyzed"
  }
 }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping

Comment: What is your elasticsearch version?

Comment: ES version : 2.3.1

Comment: I have 2.3.2 and that just works for me. Interesting.

Comment: This works for me . My problem was specifying "mapping" inside JSON also.When removed it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My ES version is 7.2,I sove this problem like this

```js
"mappings":{
 "properties":{
  "article":{
   "properties":{
    "id":{"type": "long","store": true},
    "title":{"type": "text","store": true,"index": true,"analyzer": "standard"},
    "content":{"type": "text","store": true,"index": true,"analyzer": "standard"}
   }
  }
 }
}
```

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping)