# Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters ElasticSearch API

Tags: elasticsearch, command-line-interface, sense

I am trying to design analyzers for Tokenization, Case folding, Stopword removal, Word N-gram extraction and Stemming, however after writing the code it keeps popping up errors. Index name is articles and type name is article. I already tried deleting and recreating the index severally, iam very new to elasticsearch so my codes may be very wrong, please help out.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT http://localhost:9200/articles/_mapping/article -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "content_tokenizer": {
          "type": "standard",
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        },
        "content_case_folding": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "content_stopword_removal": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop"
          ]
        },
        "content_ngram_extraction": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "ngram"
          ]
        },
        "content_stemmer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "ngram",
            "stemmer"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "ngram": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5
        },
        "stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        },
        "stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "tokenized": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "content_tokenizer"
          },
          "case_folded": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "content_case_folding"
          },
          "without_stopwords": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "content_stopword_removal"
          },
          "ngrammed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "content_ngram_extraction"
          },
          "stemmed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "content_stemmer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

It keeps bringing this error

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [settings : {analysis={analyzer={content_tokenizer={type=standard, tokenizer=standard}, content_case_folding={type=custom, tokenizer=standard, filter=[lowercase]}, content_stopword_removal={type=custom, tokenizer=standard, filter=[lowercase, stop]}, content_ngram_extraction={type=custom, tokenizer=standard, filter=[lowercase, stop, ngram]}, content_stemmer={type=custom, tokenizer=standard, filter=[lowercase, stop, ngram, stemmer]}}, filter={ngram={type=ngram, min_gram=2, max_gram=5}, stop={type=stop, stopwords=*english*}, stemmer={type=stemmer, language=english}}}}] [mappings : {properties={content={type=text, fields={tokenized={type=text, analyzer=content_tokenizer}, case_folded={type=text, analyzer=content_case_folding}, without_stopwords={type=text, analyzer=content_stopword_removal}, ngrammed={type=text, analyzer=content_ngram_extraction}, stemmed={type=text, analyzer=content_stemmer}}}}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [settings : {analysis={analyzer={content_tokenizer={type=standard, tokenizer=standard}, content_case_folding={type=custom, tokenizer=standard, filter=[lowercase]}, content_stopword_removal={type=custom, tokenizer=standard, filter=[lowercase, stop]}, content_ngram_extraction={type=custom, tokenizer=standard, filter=[lowercase, stop, ngram]}, content_stemmer={type=custom, tokenizer=standard, filter=[lowercase, stop, ngram, stemmer]}}, filter={ngram={type=ngram, min_gram=2, max_gram=5}, stop={type=stop, stopwords=*english*}, stemmer={type=stemmer, language=english}}}}] [mappings : {properties={content={type=text, fields={tokenized={type=text, analyzer=content_tokenizer}, case_folded={type=text, analyzer=content_case_folding}, without_stopwords={type=text, analyzer=content_stopword_removal}, ngrammed={type=text, analyzer=content_ngram_extraction}, stemmed={type=text, analyzer=content_stemmer}}}}}]"},"status":400}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523710/root-mapping-definition-has-unsupported-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

The URL simply needs to be this, i.e. you're creating an index with mappings and settings, you're not simply modifying an existing index mapping:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT http://localhost:9200/articles -d '{...}'
```